# How to change the push notification type in xamarin ios

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.ios

I configured push notification in xamarin ios using azure notification hub. am able to receive notification from hub. if the app is running or am using, the notification coming as an alert instead of the bar notification on top. what should i do to receive bar notification on top instead of an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate?language=objc)

To achieve your expect effect ,you should disable the alert(AlertViewController maybe) first, and implement the delegate.

#### AppDelegate

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert, (approved, err) =>
{
    // Handle the user approval or refusal of your notifications...
});
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new MyUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate();
return true;
}
```

#### MyUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

```
public class MyUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
    }
}
```

This should be able to show the Notification on the top when your app in foreground.